# Question about sums with a negative limit for the index

Tags: notation, summation, convention

To me, it looks like we have $\;\sum_{i = 1}^{0} x_i = 0\;$ and $\;\sum_{i = 1}^{1} x_i = x_1\;$. What happens if I write the following?
$$\;\sum_{i = 1}^{-123} x_i\;$$ Would this be defined?

Comment: I suggest comparing $\sum_{i=1}^kx_k$ with $\int_{t=0}^kf(t)dt$ and seeing what happens when $k$ changes sign or goes to zero. If you choose $f$ to be a suitable step function, the sum and integral are actually the same and the analogue should shed some light on your problem.

Answer (score 2):

There are different conventions:

- the sum is $0$;
- the expression is undefined;
- the expression is interpreted as $\displaystyle\sum_{i=-123}^1x_i$.

In my experience the first is the most common, and the last is quite uncommon.

Comment: Almost $99.99\%$ of the time the first one will hold.